# Exclusive Limits on Form Fields

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have the following field in a Django form:

```
area = forms.FloatField(required=False, min_value=0, max_value=100)
```

How do I make the minimum limit *exclusive* and the maximum limit *inclusive*?

[The Django page on this form](https://django-document-cn.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/forms/fields.html#floatfield) doesn't mention anything about exclusivity versus inclusivity. And looking at the source code makes me think this isn't directly built into Django. Am I right? If so, how could I work around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a custom validator to do it.  They're not complex, and the existing `MinValueValidator` and `MaxValueValidator` in `django.core.validators` will give you a good starting point.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#writing-validators

```
class ExclusiveMinValueValidator(BaseValidator):
    compare = lambda self, a, b: a <= b
    message = _(u'Ensure this value is greater than %(limit_value)s.')
    code = 'min_value'
```

You could also write a custom `clean` method for the field.

Comment: Actually, after using this in practice, I believe you need `code='limit_value'` in order for this to work.

Comment: It should work either way - the code value will be used when building the ValidationError if this is violated.  This is exactly the same as the build in `MinValueValidator` except that it tests `<=` rather than `<`.

Comment: I tried what you put and your `message` wouldn't show up. But the problem went away with `code='limit_value'`. That's just what happened. Looking at `django.core.validators.BaseValidator.__call__()`, I believe it is important how that `params` variable is set and passed into the `ValidationError`.

Comment: Were you getting the default "less than or equal to" message, or were you getting no message at all?

Comment: I was getting the default "less than or equal to" message.

Comment: I see that there are default error messages defined for `IntegerField` in django.forms.fields, and that `FloatField` inherits from them.  I am surprised to find that those override the message defined in the validator itself, but I expect that's what's going on - no default error message is defined for `code='limit_value'`.

Answer (score 2):

I would write a custom clean_field method in your form like so:

```
def clean_area(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data['area']
    if (data > 0 and data <= 100):
        return ValidationError("Some custom message alerting the user!")
    return data
```

The method just has to return the value you want, see the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute)

Then, just re-define your field as:

```
area = forms.FloatField(required=False)  # see additional clean field method
```

Comment: Still a great answer. But I ended up using Peter's solution.

Comment: Yeah, both approaches are totally viable.  I think the custom validator is better if you have multiple fields you want to do this on, or if you want to apply it at the model level.  But there's nothing wrong with a custom clean method either.

Comment: @theJollySin no worries, glad you found an answer. Validators are definitely useful to avoid the same validation code in multiple places. I should start using them more.